# Why is Azure Add > Worker role project in solution … greyed out in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have a C# .Net 4 class library that I think I have set up to be an Azure Worker Role, i.e. the class implements Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEntryPoint and has a Run() and an OnStart() method. However when I right-click on the Roles folder in my empty Windows Azure project and click Add the option to add a "Worker role project in solution …" is greyed out. What do I need to do for VS2010 to realise there's a potential worker role project in the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The "**Add > Worker Role Project in solution...**" only displays worker role projects not class libraries. Even though they look the same, they aren't.

You can create a worker role project by using the following:

- When creating a new cloud project

[image]

- By right clicking a cloud project

[image]

Then you'll be able to add that worker role project in an other cloud project if you like. In that case the "**Add > Worker Role Project in solution...**" menu option will be enabled.

Now, you can also 'convert' a class library to a worker role project. Right click the class library and choose **Unload Project** .. then (once that's unloaded),  **Edit Project File** and add the **RoleType** element in the first property group:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
   <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
   <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
   <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
   <ProjectGuid>{7E9F972F-BE92-4CF7-998D-E76B61B21C37}</ProjectGuid>
   <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
   <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
   <RootNamespace>ClassLibrary1</RootNamespace>
   <AssemblyName>ClassLibrary1</AssemblyName>
   <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
   <RoleType>Worker</RoleType>  <-------------------- HERE
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Finally - reload the project back into the solution -> Right-Click **Reload Project**. (NOTE: if the Xml file is still open, you'll get asked to close it.. which is perfect. Say yes and close it). .. Now your *class library* has been re-added back but it's a *Worker Role Class Library*.

If you do this, Visual Studio will recognize the project as being a worker role and you'll be able to add it to the cloud project:

[image]

**Note:** Your class library will need a class deriving from **RoleEntryPoint**. More information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2010/02/11/windows-azure-roleentrypoint-method-call-order.aspx

Comment: Interestingly there was no "Edit Project File" when I right clicked the class library but it was straightforward to edit it in Notepad.

Comment: Ah sorry, it could be that this button is only available through a VS extension (VSCommands, PowerCommands or Productivity Power Tools). In that case, editing in notepad is also a valid solution.

Comment: You can "Unload project" and then right click the Unloaded project to edit it.

Comment: Solid Sandrino, many thanks, added the RoleType tag in the proj file and it worked like a champ.

Comment: Perfect @SandrinoDiMattia :) Just added the Unload project stuff to the answer.